# How to define mutually exclusive query parameters in Swagger (OpenAPI)?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have a series of parameters in Swagger like this

```js
                    "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "username",
                        "description": "Fetch username by username/email",
                        "required": false,
                        "type": "string",
                        "paramType": "query"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "site",
                        "description": "Fetch username by site",
                        "required": false,
                        "type": "string",
                        "paramType": "query"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "survey",
                        "description": "Fetch username by survey",
                        "required": false,
                        "type": "string",
                        "paramType": "query"
                    }
                ],
```

One parameter MUST be filled out but it doesn't matter which one, the others can be left blank. Is there a way to represent this in Swagger?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it looks like this functionality just isn't available

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible currently. "required" is just a boolean and there's no way to represent interdependencies between parameters.

Best you can do is make clear the requirements in the parameter descriptions and also put in a custom 400 Bad Request description along the same lines.

There's a bit of discussion at https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/256 about possible ways of implementing this in the next version of the OpenAPI Specification.

Comment: OpenAPI 3.0 has a way to describe mutually exclusive parameters, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49199240/113116).

Answer (score 46):

Mutually exclusive parameters are possible (sort of) in [OpenAPI 3.x](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.1.0.md):

- Define the mutually exclusive parameters as object properties, and use `oneOf` or `maxProperties` to limit the object to just 1 property.
- Use the [parameter serialization method](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#query) `style: form` and `explode: true`, so that the object is serialized as `?propName=value`.

An example using the `minProperties` and `maxProperties` constraints:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...
paths:
  /foo:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: filter
          required: true
          style: form
          explode: true
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              username:
                type: string
              site:
                type: string
              survey:
                type: string
            minProperties: 1
            maxProperties: 1
            additionalProperties: false
```

Using `oneOf`:

```yaml
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: filter
          required: true
          style: form
          explode: true
          schema:
            type: object
            oneOf:
              - properties:
                  username:
                    type: string
                required: [username]
                additionalProperties: false
              - properties:
                  site:
                    type: string
                required: [site]
                additionalProperties: false
              - properties:
                  survey:
                    type: string
                required: [survey]
                additionalProperties: false
```

Another version using `oneOf`:

```yaml
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: filter
          required: true
          style: form
          explode: true
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              username:
                type: string
              site:
                type: string
              survey:
                type: string
            additionalProperties: false
            oneOf:
              - required: [username]
              - required: [site]
              - required: [survey]
```

Note that Swagger UI and Swagger Editor do not support the examples above yet (as of March 2018). [This issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3558) seems to cover the parameter rendering part.

There's also an open proposal in the OpenAPI Specification repository to [support interdependencies between query parameters](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/256) so maybe future versions of the Specification will have a better way to define such scenarios.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious? As this doesn't seem to do any validation for me on aws' api gateway

Comment: @omega_prime AWS API Gateway [doesn't support `oneOf`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html#api-gateway-known-issues-rest-apis) and some other OpenAPI features.

Answer (score 6):

What about changing your API design ?
Currently you have one method, 3 parameters. If I understand well, user must always provide exactly one parameter, and two remaining ones must be unset.

For me, API would be more usable with three endpoints -like

```
/user/byName?name=
/user/bySite?name=
/user/bySurvey?name=
```

Comment: Solves the technical issue but isn't very Restful.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to pass in a filter type parameter with an enum, and a filter value with the value to use.

Example at: https://app.swaggerhub.com/api/craig_bayley/PublicAPIDemo/v1

It can be required or not, as you choose. However if one is required, they should both be.

Comment: do I understand correctly, that in this case your proposal, in this case, would produce API /users?name=name&filterType=[name|site|survey] ?

I agree because this is more Restfull, because we have single resource, as it should be (still having clean and usable API).