# How do I define a swagger spec for 2 apis with same base path but different request structures?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, jsdoc

Example:

This is the first definition:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /a/b/items:
 *   get:
 *     description: Get all the items
 *     responses:
 *      200:
 *          Returns an array of items
 */
```

This is the 2nd definition:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /a/b/items:
 *   get:
 *     description: Get items by ids
 *     parameters:
 *      - name: ids
 *        in: query
 *        required: true
 *        schema:
 *          $ref: '#/definitions/itemIds'
 *
 *     responses:
 *      200:
 *          description: Returns an array of items, given the itemIds
 */
```

It is clear that, the difference here lies in the request structure.
**Note that, for the second definition, I wanna pass the parameter ids in query.**

The first definition is a simple get request without any path parameters or query parameters.

The second definition is a get request with same base path but with query params.

When I define these two in succession, the second definition over writes the first one and the Swagger UI shows the second one only.

**It's highly desirable to have these two definitions as unique ones.**

Any solutions/thoughts/ways to accomplish the uniqueness?

Changing the apis to support documentation is simply a "No go"!

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Removing the first definition and having 2nd definition with required: false for the query param and suitable description will provide a temporary solution.

But since these 2 definitions are wrt 2 unique endpoints, it is highly desirable to have 2 unique definitions.

Comment: OpenAPI/Swagger [does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40495880/113116) paths that only differ in query parameters. You can either have a single path with an optional query parameter, or change the 2nd path to use a path parameter instead of query parameter. There are no other ways.

Comment: Related proposals in the OpenAPI specification repository: [Accommodate legacy APIs by allowing query parameters in the path](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/123), [Querystring in Path Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/164)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the endpoint in the 2nd definition needs to be changed to:

```
/a/b/items/{ids}:
```

Comment: As I have clearly mentioned, the parameters are in query. Not path params.
Thanks for considering to answer though.

Comment: OK,  query params, not path ... got it!  Because you can't have duplicate endpoints,  how about removing the first definition, and in the 2nd definition change required: to false.  I know that you'll have to change the descriptions, but that will be unavoidable.

Comment: I can see what you are saying..
It kind of gives a temporary solution.
But, these two are 2 separate apis and it is desirable that each of them have unique definitions. Your suggestion provides a temporary solution though.