# Mutually excluding properties in swagger

Tags: swagger, openapi

How do I indicate that in my_object you can have property_1 or property_2, but not both?

```
my_object:
  type: object
  properties:
    property_1:
      type: string
    property_2:
      type: string
```

Comment: Are `property_1` and `property_2` the only properties in this object, or can it have other properties too?

Comment: @Helen, it has other properties too

Comment: Are `property1`/`property2` required (i.e. one or the other MUST be present) or are they optional (i.e. one or the other MAY be present)? Are there required properties among other properties?

Comment: @Helen, at least one of them must be present.

Comment: Related: [How to define mutually exclusive query parameters in Swagger (OpenAPI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21134029/113116), [Swagger 2.0 - how to make “one or the other” parameter required?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29708505/113116)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to switch to OpenAPI 3.0, which supports oneOf keyword to define mutually exclusive conditions:

here is an example :

```
 my_object:
 type: object
 properties:
   property_1:
     type: string
   property_2:
    type: integer
 oneOf:
- required: [property_1]
- required: [property_2]
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Mixed types != mutually exclusive properties.

Comment: @Helen , thanks for your review , I edited my response.

Comment: The question asked for mutually exclusive properties. Won't this allow for setting both `property_1` and `property_2`?

Answer (score 2):

In **OpenAPI 3.0** (`openapi: 3.0.0`), you can use the `oneOf` keyword to define mutually exclusive conditions. This schema requires that either `property_1` or `property_2` be present, but not both:

```yaml
my_object:
  type: object
  properties:
    property_1:
      type: string
    property_2:
      type: string
    property_3:
      type: string
  oneOf:
    - required: [property_1]
    - required: [property_2]
```

If *at least one* of these two properties must be present, use `anyOf` instead.

**Note:** While `oneOf` is part of the OpenAPI Specification (as in, you can write API definitions that include `oneOf`), actual tooling support for `oneOf` may vary and be limited.

If you use **OpenAPI 2.0** (`swagger: "2.0"`), it does not support `oneOf`, so you can only document this condition verbally in the schema description or property descriptions.

Comment: This does not work at least in SwaggerHub:

        roles:
          type: object
          properties:
            specific:
              type: array
              items:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Role'
            fromProto:
              type: boolean
              default: true
          oneOf:
          - required: [specific]
          - required: [fromProto]

[![Documentation results:][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGXyp.png

Comment: @cvigo Open an issue here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues