# Paths that differ only in query parameter names

Tags: rest, yaml, swagger, swagger-editor

I'm using the swagger editor to document an existing API that allows a path to support two different requests that differ only in their query parameter names. For example:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: example
  version: 1.0.0
host: example.com
schemes:
  - http
basePath: /WS
paths:
  /Login:
    post:
      summary: Login
      description: |
        Log in
      parameters:
        - name: UserID
          in: query
          description: User ID
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: Password
          in: query
          description: User password
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
  /Login:
    post:
      summary: Login
      description: |
        Log in
      parameters:
        - name: UserID
          in: query
          description: User ID
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: Token
          in: query
          description: Authentication token
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
```

Here I support requests to `http://example.com/WS/Login?UserID=foo&Passoword=bar` and `http://example.com/WS/Login?UserID=foo&Token=dubdu22r8dwjgd767dg`.

The swagger editor doesn't show any errors for the above yaml, but it only generates documentation for the *second* path (the one with UserId and Token queryparams), not both. Can someone point out where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

**Edit:**

If I change the second `/Login:` path to (for example) `/Login1:` then I see both paths in the documentation. Not a solution though.

It also occurs to me that I could specify one `/Login:` path with a required `UserID` parameter and optional `Password` and `Token` parameters. But how do I specify that *exactly one* of `UserID` and `Password` must be supplied?

Comment: Related (or duplicate of): [How to define mutually exclusive query parameters in Swagger (OpenAPI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134029/how-to-define-mutually-exclusive-query-parameters-in-swagger-openapi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use path parameters instead, try with:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: example
  version: 1.0.0
host: example.com
schemes:
  - http
basePath: /WS
paths:
  /Login?UserID={id}&Password={password}:
    post:
      summary: Login
      description: Log in
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          description: User ID
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: password
          in: path
          description: User password
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
  /Login?UserID={id}&Token={token}:
    post:
      summary: Login
      description: Log in
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          description: User ID
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: token
          in: path
          description: Authentication token
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem: I didn't include the queryparams in the paths. Can't believe I missed that! Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is not a valid Swagger 2.0 spec. Query parameters are not allowed in paths.