# Ignore parameter when one other similar is passed in swagger def

Tags: rest, swagger, jsonschema

I have the following swagger definition parameter section:

```
parameters:
  - name: language
    in: query
    required: false
    type: string
  - name: Accept-Language
    in: header
    type: string
```

What I'm trying to describe is the following scenario; the parameter `Accept-Language` is ignored when the `language` param is passed as input. Do you have any idea? JSON Schema probably is the answer to this but not sure how to orchestrate the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define mutually exclusive query parameters in Swagger (OpenAPI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134029/how-to-define-mutually-exclusive-query-parameters-in-swagger-openapi)