# How to require at least one of two parameters in OpenAPI?

Tags: openapi

I'm using OpenAPI 3 and have two query parameters, at least *one* of which is required but it doesn't matter which.

I.e., as sudocode:

```
if parameter_1 OR parameter_2:
    do stuff
else:
    error
```

Is this possible in OpenAPI 3? There's no mention of it in the spec as far as I can see, or the JSON Schema spec either.

Comment: Do you mean `parameters` (e.g. query/header params) or model/schema `properties`?

Comment: Related: [How to define mutually exclusive query parameters in Swagger (OpenAPI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21134029/113116)

Comment: @Helen - Query parameters. Your answer in that question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49199240/1316981) does indeed answer my question. Alas it didn't come up in my search. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

This scenario is very similar to [mutually exclusive parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49199240/113116). Basically, you can use an object-type parameter where `parameter_1` and `parameter_2` are the object properties; such object will be [serialized](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/#query) as `?parameter_1=value1&parameter_2=value2`. The "at least one of" constraint can be represented using `minProperties` or `anyOf`.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.2
...
paths:
  /foo:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: param
          required: true
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              parameter_1:
                type: string
              parameter_2:
                type: string
            additionalProperties: false

            # Option 1
            minProperties: 1

            # Option 2
            # anyOf:
            #  - required: [parameter_1]
            #  - required: [parameter_2]
```

There's also an existing feature request to support interdependencies between individual parameters in the `parameters` list:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/256

Comment: This did not work for me. The Kotlin OpenAPI generator (`v6.6.0`) will give me: `fun foo(@NotNull  @Valid &#x60;param&#x60;: FooParamParameter)`, which even doesn't compile :(

Comment: It's a tooling issue. Open a bug with OpenAPI Generator: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues

Comment: When I put this into the Swagger Editor and go to try it, despite it being in:query it tries to tell me that parameters are a JSON object, doesn't mention that only one must be specified, and doesn't display the description of the individual parameters.

Comment: This solution produces an error for me: `{"message": "Missing property.", "path": "/param"}`