# How to require at least one of two parameters in different locations in OpenAPI?

Tags: openapi

I am using OpenAPI 3.0 to describe the schema of the APIs which are running. I have to require two parameters in different locations. What I want to achieve:

```
parameters:
  - oneOf:
    - in: cookie
      name: username
      description: User's name
      schema:
        type: string
      required: true
    - in: query
      name: nickname
      description: User's nickname
      schema:
        type: string
      required: true
```

I have read

- [How to require at least one of two parameters in OpenAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53782328/how-to-require-at-least-one-of-two-parameters-in-openapi)
- [How to define mutually exclusive query parameters in Swagger (OpenAPI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134029/how-to-define-mutually-exclusive-query-parameters-in-swagger-openapi/49199240#49199240)

But those solutions only solve the problems when the parameters are in the same location, so they did not solve my problem.

Comment: This is a great question but I'm not sure it is possible. This seems like application logic more than something you can require in an API description