# .Net Core 5: WebApi query string parameters

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, openapi, asp.net-core-5.0

Is it possible to Swagger a Get Api with one parameter that can be different in name?
I Explain, I should create a controller that can have this behaviour:

```
GET <MySite>/suppliers?srm=0016018132
GET <MySite>/suppliers?vat=02123420040
```

srm and vat are mutually exclusive. A user can call one of two form of the api.

Comment: Edit the title to reflect the question. You aren't asking about WebAPI parameters. You're asking whether OpenAPI can express that two parameters are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define mutually exclusive query parameters in Swagger (OpenAPI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134029/how-to-define-mutually-exclusive-query-parameters-in-swagger-openapi)

Answer (score 0):

#### short answer

no

#### a little longer answer

where in c# a method's "uniqueness" derives from the name and parameter order/type, in a web api only a method's *name* determines "uniqueness".

Comment: The question is really about Open API, not method parameters. One can write validation code to express any kind of restriction. It's possible to create middleware that does the same. The real question is if that can be expressed in the Open API document

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I respectively disagree. Open Api is generated *from* the Controller's Actions. Actions are fancy names for methods. It's also a *bit* presumptuous of you to dictate to the OP and myself what you *want* the question to be about.

Comment: Check [How to define mutually exclusive query parameters in Swagger (OpenAPI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21134029/how-to-define-mutually-exclusive-query-parameters-in-swagger-openapi). Generating an Open API document from actions is just one way to do it but not the most flexible. So the short answer is *Yes, more or less*