# Cross-dependency of attributes in OpenAPI 3.0

Tags: json, openapi, anyof

I need to define swagger/OpenAPI v 3.0 file for a search API.
My request can specify either geospatial coordinates (longitude and latitude) or (postal code and country code) or (city and state and country code).
Beside these I do have couple more mandatory attributes, like ***distance*** and ***distanceUnits***.

I know how to do it in JSON schema

```
            "dependencies": {
                "postalCode": ["countryCode"],
                "city": ["state", "countryCode"],
                "longitude": ["latitude"],
                "latitude": ["longitude"]
            },
            "anyOf": [
                {
                    "required": ["longitude", "latitude"]
                },
                {
                    "required": ["postalCode", "countryCode"]
                },
                {
                    "required": ["city", "state", "countryCode"]
                }
            ]
        }
```

but I have troubles defining it in swagger. OpenAPI 3.0 allows ***oneOf*** and ***anyOf*** constructs, but if I am trying to use it in ***required*** section, swagger editor gives me an error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define `oneOf`/`anyOf` logic for request parameters, you would have to define all parameters as a single object-type parameter, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49199240/113116).

```yaml
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: params  # This name will NOT appear in the request URL
                  # but will be used in generated client SDKs / server stubs
    required: true

    # serialize this object as ?key1=value1&key2=value2
    style: form
    explode: true

    schema:
      type: object
      properties:
        longitude: { ... }
        latitude:  { ... }
        postalCode:  { ... }
        countryCode: { ... }
        city:  { ... }
        state: { ... }
      anyOf:
        - required: [longitude, latitude]
        - required: [postalCode, countryCode]
        - required: [city, state, countryCode]
```

Note that OpenAPI 3.0 does not support the `dependencies` keyword of JSON Schema, but it's supported in OpenAPI 3.1 (the latest version).

There's also an existing feature request in the OpenAPI Specification repository to [support dependencies between individual parameter definitions](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/256).

Comment: Thank you. However, is OpenAPI 3.1 published? I did not find it on https://swagger.io/resources/open-api/ page

Comment: OAS 3.1 was published in February 2021 - https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0.html. But currently there's almost no tooling support for it.