# How to define in swagger spec both of two properties are not null or both are null?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have object descriptions like this:

```yaml
SomeEntity:
  description: description
  properties:
    prop1:
      nullable: true
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Field1'
   prop2:
      nullable: true
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Field2'
```

Then I've decided to add 2 more properties

```yaml
SomeEntity:
  description: description
  properties:
    prop1:
      nullable: true
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Field1'
    prop2:
      nullable: true
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Field2'
    prop3:
      nullable: true
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Field3'
    prop4:
      nullable: true
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Field4'
```

I want to add condition that `prop3` and `prop4` should be both null or `prop3` and `prop4` or both not null.

Is there way to achieve it using Open API 3.0?

Comment: can you clarify your meaning of null?  null as in the property is a null value, empty value, or the property is not expected to be in the payload?

Comment: I mean both: property is not present in payload or it is defined as null

Comment: usually allOf or anyOf allow you to put multiple schema types for a given property, I'm not sure what it achieves here given there is only a single choice for each `prop` type. You could try something like this (its talking about parameters but I would expect the same usage would apply to schema types): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69166438/cross-dependency-of-attributes-in-openapi-3-0/69167451#69167451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two properties to be either both `null` or both not `null`, you can use the `oneOf` and `anyOf` keywords, which allow you to describe a list of alternative types. For example:

```yaml
allOf:
  - type: object
  properties:
      prop1:
        allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Field1
      prop2:
        allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Field2
oneOf:
  - type: object
    properties:
      prop3:
        allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Field3
      prop4:
        allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Field4
  - type: object
    properties:
      prop3:
        type: 'null'
      prop4:
        type: 'null'
```

In this example, an object must have two properties `prop3` and `prop4`, which can either both be strings or both be `null`. However, if one of the properties is a string and the other is `null`, the object will not match the schema.